# Not allow attachments in groups

Tags: google-groups

I  am the owner of a Google group. I want to not allow attachments sent when people use the reply to all option or send to the group using the email address @googlegroups.com but not working?

Answer (score 2):

So you have the 'Attach Files' permission disabled for normal members in Permissions / Posting permissions?

Of course, if you only want them not to be able add attachments when posting by email, but still want them to be able to do that when posting using the group web interface - then that's just not possible.